# Using password protection to load different page elements?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, security, password

I have a page that is password protected, and I wish to removed some parts of the theme, and add others. Can I do that? Is there a check I can do in the theme files to see if a user has entered the password or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`post_password_required()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required) conditional:

```
<?php
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    // Post is password-protected; do something
} else {
    // Post is NOT password-protected; do something else
}
?>
```